# Configuring Drupal to work with an existing webapp

Tags: apache, drupal, drupal-7

I have an existing web application which I have been building with an ant script and deploying as a .war file to Tomcat.

I am trying to add Drupal to my current technology stack to provide CMS and general UI-related functionality so that I don't have to write my html pages by hand and rather use templates.

During the installation of Drupal7, some of the instructions suggest that I go to this directory:

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

and change the DocumentRoot to

```
/home/myuser/drupal/drupal7
```

If I make the docroot a basic directory on the file system, how will this impact how the application will work?  In addition to Apache, I also have Tomcat server.  My goal is to get them to all play nice together.  How is this best accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I make the docroot a basic directory on the filesystem

I'm not sure what you mean by this.  There's no qualitative difference between /var/www and /home/mysuser/drupal/drupal7.  The latter is longer and in the user's home directory, but assuming this user would be administering the service anyway that doesn't matter.

Next, the best way to make Tomcat and Apache get along is *probably* to run one of them on different subdomains.  You could use the same domain, but that'd mean you had to run one of the daemons off a nonstandard port and that looks strange and might run into firewall trouble with some users.